# How to get started using NICE DCV SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am trying out the [NICE DCV SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/dcv/) from AWS, documentation linked [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/websdkguide/what-is.html)
But I can't figure out how to run the example given on the docs page. I tried running it in a node server but get this error:

```
ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

So, it would be fantastic if someone could help me get started with the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/websdkguide/establish-connection.html).

Edit: I tried simply opening the index.html from a browser as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply copying the [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/websdkguide/establish-connection.html) from the Developer Guide, hence having:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DCV first connection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        <div id="dcv-display"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import "./dcvjs/dcv.js";

let auth,
    connection,
    serverUrl;

function onPromptCredentials(auth, challenge) {
    // Let's check if in challenge we have a username and password request
    if (challengeHasField(challenge, "username") && challengeHasField(challenge, "password")) {
        auth.sendCredentials({username: "my_dcv_user", password: "my_password"})
    } else {
        // Challenge is requesting something else...
    }
}

function challengeHasField(challenge, field) {
    return challenge.requiredCredentials.some(credential => credential.name === field);
}

function onError(_, error) {
    console.log("Error during the authentication: ", error.message);
}

// We connect to the first session returned
function onSuccess(_, result) {
    let {sessionId, authToken} = {...result[0]};
    connect(sessionId, authToken);
}

function connect (sessionId, authToken) {
    console.log(sessionId, authToken);
    dcv.connect({
        url: serverUrl,
        sessionId: sessionId,
        authToken: authToken,
        divId: "dcv-display",
        callbacks: {
            firstFrame: () => console.log("First frame received")
        }
    }).then(function (conn) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
        connection= conn;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Connection failed with error " + error.message);
    });
}

function main () {
    console.log("Setting log level to INFO");
    dcv.setLogLevel(dcv.LogLevel.INFO);
    serverUrl = "https://your-dcv-server-url:port/";
    console.log("Starting authentication with", serverUrl);
    auth = dcv.authenticate(
        serverUrl,
        {
            promptCredentials: onPromptCredentials,
            error: onError,
            success: onSuccess
        }
    );
}

console.log("Using NICE DCV Web Client SDK version " + dcv.version.versionStr);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
```

changing the *username*, *password* and *serverUrl*, should work in a web environment.

I was also able to serve it from a node.js server set up as in the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Node_server_without_framework

Comment: Thank you for the guide! However I am encountering an error saying connection not private as commented in the answer from below.  Please help me with solving that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have created a demo of the NICE DCV SDK integration. Please try it or download it from https://www.ni-sp.com/DCVSDK/

Here are the 2 files including the bonus **login form** and a couple of issues fixed (please adapt the serverUrl in main.js):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>DCV first connection</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="main.js"></script>
        <div id="dcv-display"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
import "./dcvjs/dcv.js"
let auth,
    connection,
    serverUrl;

console.log("Using NICE DCV Web Client SDK version " + dcv.version.versionStr);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);

function main () {
    console.log("Setting log level to INFO");
    dcv.setLogLevel(dcv.LogLevel.INFO);

    serverUrl = "https://your-dcv-server-url:port/";
    
    console.log("Starting authentication with", serverUrl);

    auth = dcv.authenticate(
        serverUrl,
        {
            promptCredentials: onPromptCredentials2,
            error: onError,
            success: onSuccess
        }
    );
}


function onPromptCredentials(auth, challenge) {
    // Let's check if in challege we have a username and password request
    if (challengeHasField(challenge, "username") && challengeHasField(challenge, "password")) {
        auth.sendCredentials({username: "YOURUSER", password: "YOUR_PW"})
    } else {
        // Challenge is requesting something else...
    }
}

function challengeHasField(challenge, field) {
    return challenge.requiredCredentials.some(credential => credential.name === field);
}

function onError(auth, error) {
    console.log("Error during the authentication: ", error.message);
}

// We connect to the first session returned
function onSuccess(auth, result) {
    let {sessionId, authToken} = {...result[0]};

    connect(sessionId, authToken);
}

function connect (sessionId, authToken) {
    console.log(sessionId, authToken);

    dcv.connect({
        url: serverUrl,
        sessionId: sessionId,
        authToken: authToken,
        divId: "dcv-display",
        callbacks: {
            firstFrame: () => console.log("First frame received")
        }
    }).then(function (conn) {
        console.log("Connection established!");
        connection= conn;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Connection failed with error " + error.message);
    });
}


function submitCredentials (e) {
    var credentials = {};
    fieldSet.childNodes.forEach(input => credentials[input.id] = input.value);
    auth.sendCredentials(credentials);
    e.preventDefault();
}

var fieldSet;

function createLoginForm () {
    var submitButton = document.createElement("button");

    submitButton.type = "submit";
    submitButton.textContent = "Login";

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    fieldSet = document.createElement("fieldset");

    form.onsubmit = submitCredentials;
    form.appendChild(fieldSet);
    form.appendChild(submitButton);

    document.body.appendChild(form);
}

function addInput (name) {
    var type = name === "password" ? "password" : "text";

    var inputField = document.createElement("input");
    inputField.name = name;
    inputField.id = name;
    inputField.placeholder = name;
    inputField.type = type;
    fieldSet.appendChild(inputField);
}

function onPromptCredentials2 (_, credentialsChallenge) {
    createLoginForm();
    credentialsChallenge.requiredCredentials.forEach(challenge => addInput(challenge.name));
}
```

Comment: Hi @KarstenNISP, thank you for the code! I somehow got the example code(no idea how :) ), however I encounter an error `Using NICE DCV Web Client SDK version 1.0.0+build.81
main.mjs:11 Setting log level to INFO
main.mjs:16 Starting authentication with https://my-ip:8443
dcv.js:2 WebSocket connection to 'wss://my-ip:8443/auth' failed: 
uf @ dcv.js:2
main.mjs:42 Error during the authentication:  Failed to communicate with server
dcv.js:2 [authentication] Auth WebSocket connection closed. Code 1006` i had a real ip in place of my-ip. I get this running yours as well. Please help :)

Comment: @guidingfox Can you test connecting from a web browser to https://my-ip:8443? Is your firewall open for 8443 incoming?

Comment: @KarstenNISP When I connect to https://my-ip:8443/ I get a warning from chrome `Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 13.127.108.183 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` But I can still manually override this error.

Comment: That is normal in case you do not have installed a certificate for your DNS name. Please accept the message and try again via the browser to verify it works and then via the SDK integration.

Comment: Hi @KarstenNISP That's seems to have fixed it when I go to https://www.ni-sp.com/DCVSDK/ though it still didn't fix it for my code. But I am not sure how to fix the issue if I am to use it for deployment to my website. Also thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @KarstenNISP Also My idea is to use NICE DCV for giving access to our users to some apps/games running on EC2 instances. Does this mean I will have to implement the session manager API? And any advise on the legalities of using NICE DCV for free for this purpose would be wonderful

Comment: @guidingfox - you can use NICE DCV for free on AWS. Depending on how many users you want to support DCV SM can fit very well. DCV also supports MFA in case. Please reach out to us via email (at NI SP) for further details as this seems not to be the right platform for this.

Comment: Hey Guys, @KarstenNISP I have a simillar issue.

Hello Guys, I hope you are doing good!

1 - I have used the example here:
https://www.ni-sp.com/DCVSDK
And when I put my machine address, it works fine. 

But, when I download the example and try to run it on my machine, on a local server, it doesn't work anymore. The authentication error on websocket shows up. So, my nice dcv instance is fine, I just can't connect to it from my local network using the SDK but I can connect from the browser or desktop client.

Comment: Additionally, 

2 - Is there any way to open the desktop client already with user and password filled?
For example, if I type on the browser:
dcv://[my-ip]:8443

It will ask me to open my client and skip the IP part. But I didn't find a way to send the username and password so that the client could connect directly.

Can you help me with that too?

Comment: Hi @GuilhermeAssemany, please make sure your website hosting the SDK is accessible via https as otherwise a mix of http and https for the DCV connection will cause issues with browser security. Regards automatically providing the username and password this can be achieved with additional javascript either supported from the server-side via patches or via greasemonkey or similar on the frontend in case that is an option.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is wondering that Ni-sp site works and not yours. Here is the solution:

The web server & DCV Server both need to have a certificate assigned to them when both trust (most probably an internal root CA) and the client connecting to the Web server must have the root certificates so that it can validate the web server and DCV server certificates.

I tested it worked correctly. Without a valid certificate, you will get the exception

> Error during the authentication:  Failed to communicate with server
> dcv.js:2 [authentication] Auth WebSocket connection closed. Code 1006

Comment: Thank you for the input Nalin.
I'm running the sample html app in localhost.
But it wouldn't connect. Fails saying "Cannot communicate with server"

Can you please explain the Certificate needed for the server? Or route me to any documentation on that, please?