# NICE DCV Client with dockerized vue application

Tags: javascript, docker, vue.js, x11-forwarding

I'm working on a vue application that processes data on another server via API requests and an SSH connection. Yesterday I noticed that there is also a NICE DCV server running on the server, which can be accessed via the NICE DCV client application.

Is there a way to embed a NICE DCV client in the vue application, for example with iframe or with a new tab. I have already unsuccessfully tried to run a NICE DCV client in an X11 Ubuntu container. Maybe there is a better way to implement that.

Thank you for ideas ;)

Comment: How about this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303552/how-to-get-started-using-nice-dcv-sdk/67335297 ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.