# Running AWS NICE DCV releases web client SDK using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services

I tried to follow this example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dcv/latest/websdkguide/establish-connection.html
and I even looked at other stack-overflow questions [How to get started using NICE DCV SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67303552/how-to-get-started-using-nice-dcv-sdk)

I'm trying to run the js file using Node. I'm getting the error

```
/NI-SP-DCVSDK-Demo-1.0/dcvjs/dcv.js:346
     window.hasOwnProperty("webkitAudioContext") &&
     ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at file:///Users/chandu/Downloads/NI-SP-DCVSDK-Demo-1.0/dcvjs/dcv.js:346:6
    at file:///Users/chandu/Downloads/NI-SP-DCVSDK-Demo-1.0/dcvjs/dcv.js:451:5
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:138:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:178:24)
```

I'm a beginner at nodejs. please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The NICE DCV SDK needs to be executed in a browser as the NICE DCV web client runs in the web browser. It cannot be executed in nodejs.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to connect to dcv using a headless client.

Comment: You need a browser or something emulating the browser providing a window object. Did you try with a real browser first?